# Django FULL JOIN

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm experiencing some struggles with querying data with Django ORM.

Database for a store. Each employee has a yearly goal for sold and reserved phone of different models.

**Diagram of my tables so far**
[image: Diagram of my tables so far]
**These tables can be matched by (seller, phone_model) combination**

My models so far

```
class SoldReserved(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_model = models.ForeignKey(
        PhoneModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    # this field will contain the status information E.g. "sold" or "reserved"
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)



class SellGoal(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [["seller", "phone_model", "year"]]

    id = ShortUUIDField(length=16, max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_model = models.ForeignKey(
        PhoneModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    year = models.SmallIntegerField()
    goal = models.IntegerField()



class ReserveGoal(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [["seller", "phone_model", "year"]]

    id = ShortUUIDField(length=16, max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_model = models.ForeignKey(
        PhoneModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    year = models.SmallIntegerField()
    goal = models.IntegerField()
```

There can be some sold phones without any associated goals. And there can be goals, that don't have associated entries in SoldReserved table. My goal here is to fetch all for all goals and for all SoldReserved entries. After fetching I'm going to annotate the queryset and serialize it with serializer:

```
class SoldReservedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    employee_name = serializers.CharField()
    phone_modle = serializers.CharField()
    sell_goal = serializers.IntegerField()
    sell_actual = serializers.IntegerField()
    reserved_goal = serializers.IntegerField()
    reserved_actual = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Data on the frontend should be presented in the following form:
[image]

My problem: somehow, I need to query all the data(including SoldReserved without associated goals and vice versa). What I have tried so far: querying for all SoldReserved models and then annotating like this:

```
all_sold_reserved_queryset
        .annotate(
            seller_name=F("seller__name"),
            phone_model=F("phone_model__name"),
            sold_actual=(
                    Subquery(
                        """elevant subquery for aggregated data from SoldReservedTable"""
                    ),
                    Value(0),
            ),
            sold_goal=(
                    Subquery(
                        """Relevant subquery to SellGoal table"""
                    ),
                    Value(0),
            ),
            
            reserved_actual=(
                showroom_actual := Coalesce(
                    Subquery(
                        """Relevant subquery for aggregated data from SoldReservedTable"""
                    ),
                    Value(0),
                )
            ),
            reserved_goal=(
                    Subquery(
                       """Relevant subquery to ReserveGoal table"""
                    )
                )
            ),
```

Doing something like this results in missing SellGoal and ReserveGoal entries that don't have associated row in SoldReserved Table. I need something like a FULL JOIN here. I don't understand how can I implement this in Django.

P.s. Options with converting queryset to list and then appending missing data(or performing a union operation) won't work here. I need to have a queryset for further filtering and pagination.